# Let $n_1 = ab$ and $n_2 = ac$, where $a, b, c$ are 8-bit prime numbers. Given congruence values, find $a,b,c$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I Have the following problem:

> Let $n_1 = ab$ and $n_2 = ac$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are 8-bit prime numbers.
> You are given that $n_1 ≡ 7905 \pmod{13337}$ and $n_2 ≡ 4186 \pmod{ 13337}$. Find $a$, $b$, $c$. Also the number 13337 is prime.

I have no clue what kind of theorem I need to use in order to solve this problem, but I have found that the $\gcd(7905,4186)=1$. So they are relatively prime. Also I have the prime factorization of $7905 = 3 \times 5 \times 17 \times 31$ and of $4186 = 2 \times 7 \times 13 \times 23$, if that helps.

As I understand all of the $a$,$b$,$c$ are primes  between $2$ and $255$ since they are of 8-bits, but I am wondering if there is another way other than a brute force calculation method.

I was thinking that The Chinese Remainder Theorem could be used but the solution that I will find for the $a$ prime will still have $b$ and $c$ in it, so that's why I do not know how to solve it!

Thank you in advance for all the responses!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It is possible to use [typset mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here.  It will make your Question easier to read.

Comment: Odd mod odd is opposite parity to multiplier...

Comment: The search is pretty fast, if you use wolfram alpha or some engine that can factor small numbers rapidly.

Comment: There are only 54 prime numbers that fit in 8 bits, so a brute-force search is feasible.

Comment: $n_1=7905+13337t$ for some $t$, and $1\le n_1\le(255)^2$, so there are only, what, four or five possibilities for $n_1$. Similarly for $n_2$. And $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=a$ is an 8-bit prime, and gcd is easy to compute via Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: Gerry Myerson that is the answer that I came up with too because for some reason in my assignment it was said to not write a program that solves it but do it by hand and I was looking for a more mathematical and systematic solution and I thought that I was missing some kind of trick that would help me solve this problem or quantify it in a subcategory of some kind of CRT Problem!

Comment: It seems likely that the proposer of the original problem intended "eight bit prime" to mean those in the range from $128$ to $255$.  All such primes are of course odd, so the products $n_1,n_2$ are odd as well.  With that interpretation @Gerry's $t$ must be even, i.e. only $t=2,4$ need to be considered.

Comment: Gerry's solution in Sage/Python: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9jt0OgjAMhe%5F7FL1kSRPcUFAzn8WMyc8umGbw%5FrEFohKj567n9DvtgBfURVFUkDRhMjxWp92BcK%2DPJTxSGJqRvbGZsnm4Jhe7JjOE2tqjUtAHabBWlwDtPWHUGCIuW1LZB8JBnQFZc24%2DcrPNRY7rOn%5FLIrPRqJcfWo6YXF5674tqZvhunqPb%2DMzUvxiRF858cyvr%5F7EizuK0fkroCGtCr%2DAJL4JOqA==&lang=sage

Comment: Hey, hardmath do you know it for sure? Because it is unclear so I think that it doesn't hurt to do the whole procedure since other primes that are less than 128 can be represented with 8-bits

Comment: Also I want to clear that the solution that I proposed as a response to my question was not stolen from Gerry and I indeed happened to think of it around 4 hours before Mr. Gerry's response but I logged in like an hour ago to Formally write our answer.
Also very important I will not change the title question to write it more mathematically as some of you have very kindly suggested like Scipio Aemilianus

Comment: The reason is because I want other students that struggled with the same question to easily find it with a google search because I really think that it is beneficial to cut down on all that stupid downtime where students search for ways to solve an excercise and nothing comes up and there are no similar problems where students can learn from and better understand how to solve and think of dubious excercises like this one and many more

Answer (score 2):

A simple brute-force approach:

```
# List of all prime numbers that fit in 8 bits
PRIMES = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251]

for a in PRIMES:
    for b in PRIMES:
        if a * b % 13337 == 7905:
            for c in PRIMES:
                if a * c % 13337 == 4186:
                    print(a, b, c)
```

Which gives only one solution: $a = 229$, $b = 151$, and $c = 193$.

---

If you prefer a less brute-force approach, consider the value of $n_1 + n_2  = ab + ac = a(b + c)$.  We know two things about it:

- Since $2 \le a, b, c \le 251$, we have $8 \le a(b + c) \le 126002$
- Since $n_1 \equiv 7905 \pmod{13337}$ and $n_2 \equiv 4186 \pmod{13337}$, then $n_1 + n_2 \equiv 12091 \pmod{13337}$.  IOW, $n_1 + n_2 = 13337k + 12091$ for some integer $k$.

Combining these two statements, we get $0 \le k \le 8$.  This gives us 9 possible options of what $n_1 + n_2 = a(b + c)$ could be:

- $12091 = 107 \times 113$
- $25428 = 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 13 \times 163$
- $38765 = 5 \times 7753$
- $52102 = 2 \times 109 \times 239$
- $65439 = 3 \times 3 \times 11 \times 661$
- $78776 = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 43 \times 229$
- $92113 = 7 \times 13159$
- $105450 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 19 \times 37$
- $118787$ is prime

We can rule out those that would require a factor larger than $502$ (the maximum allowed value of $b + c$), leaving:

- $12091 = 107 \times 113$
- $25428 = 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 13 \times 163$
- $52102 = 2 \times 109 \times 239$
- $78776 = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 43 \times 229$
- $105450 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 19 \times 37$

Since $a$ must be a prime factor of one of these numbers, then:

$$a \in \{ 2, 3, 5, 13, 19, 37, 43, 107, 109, 113, 163, 229, 239 \}$$

However, $a = \frac{n_1 + n_2}{b + c} \ge \frac{12091}{251 + 251} \approx 24.085657$, so this restricts the possible values to:

$$a \in \{ 37, 43, 107, 109, 113, 163, 229, 239 \}$$

Limiting the possibilities to:

- $a(b + c) = 12091 \implies a = 107, b + c = 113$
- $a(b + c) = 12091 \implies a = 113, b + c = 107$
- $a(b + c) = 25428 \implies a = 163, b + c = 156$
- $a(b + c) = 52102 \implies a = 109, b + c = 478$
- $a(b + c) = 52102 \implies a = 239, b + c = 218$
- $a(b + c) = 78776 \implies a = 43, b + c = 1832$
- $a(b + c) = 78776 \implies a = 229, b + c = 344$
- $a(b + c) = 105450 \implies a = 37, b + c = 2850$

But as mentioned previously, having $b + c > 502$ is impossible.

Also, the only way for two primes ($b$ and $c$ to add up to an odd number is for one of them to be $2$). And since $111 = 3 \times 37$ and $105 = 3 \times 5 \times 7$ are not prime, then the solutions with $b + c = 113$ or $b + c = 107$ are ruled out.  We're now down to four possible solutions:

- $a(b + c) = 25428 \implies a = 163, b + c = 156$
- $a(b + c) = 52102 \implies a = 109, b + c = 478$
- $a(b + c) = 52102 \implies a = 239, b + c = 218$
- $a(b + c) = 78776 \implies a = 229, b + c = 344$

Now, let's solve for $b$ using $ab ≡ 7905 \pmod{13337}$.

- $a = 163 \implies b = 4876$, out of range
- $a = 109 \implies b = 9127$, out of range
- $a = 239 \implies b = 5446$, out of range
- $a = 229, b + c = 344 \implies b = 151, c = 193$

Now the only potential solution is $(a = 229, b = 151, c = 193)$.  And it can be easily verified that all three numbers are prime, and that $n_2 \equiv 4186 \pmod{13337}$.  Therefore, this is the unique solution to the problem.

Comment: You could optimize the code by putting the a*b check outside the c loop

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I would appreciate it a lot if you read my answer that I came up to the question and then comment on it if you agree, cause I really appreciate all the time and effort that you put in and providing me and anyone else who sees the post with a really cool explanation!

Comment: Setting b to the next element of primes above a to start would also half the search space. Two test per loop, but half as many test...

Answer (score 2):

$n_1=7905+13337t$ for some integer $t$, and $1\le n_1\le251^2=63001$, so $n_1=7905{\rm\ or\ }21242{\rm\ or\ }34579{\rm\ or\ }47916{\rm\ or\ }61253.$ As $n_1$ is a product of two $8$-bit primes, we can rule out candidates with obvious small divisors $7905$ and $21242$ and $47916$, so we're left with just $34579$ and $61253$.

Similarly, $n_2=4186+13337t$ so
$n_2=4186{\rm\ or\ }17523{\rm\ or\ }30860{\rm\ or\ }44197{\rm\ or\ }57534.$ Again ruling out numbers with obvious small divisors we can eliminate $4186$ and $30860$ and $57534$, leaving just $17523$ and $44197$.

Now, the $8$-bit prime $a$ divides both $n_1$ and $n_2$, so all we have to do is find $\gcd(n_1,n_2)$ for each of the four candidate pairs (this is where this solution differs from the one by OP, in computing gcds rather than trying to factor these five-digit numbers).

Using the Euclidean algorithm (but suppressing the details), we find $\gcd(34579,17523)=1$, $\gcd(34579,44197)=229$, an $8$-bit prime, so that's probably our answer. Checking, $34579=229\times151$, $44197=229\times193$, so we have an answer, and don't need to check the other two pairs.

Comment: If we assume $n_1$ is a product of two *distinct* primes, then $n_1\le241\times251=60491$, so we can rule out $n_1=61253$, and we only have two candidate pairs to test.

Comment: Wow such a concise and beautiful solution,you are the best!!!

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of headbanging and trying to find a more "appropriate and mathematical solution" I couldn't find nothing but the following, semi-brute-force, but not really, solution.

I said that the first and second modular equation can be rewritten as the following:

$\ n_1=7905+13337n$ for some $\ n$ where $\ 2 ≤ n_1 ≤ 241*251 = 60491$

$\ n_2=4186+13337t$ for some $\ t$ where $\ 2 <= n2 <= 241*251 = 60491$

(241 and 251 are the two largest 8-bit integers) (An 8-bit number is from 0 to 255 and the first and last primes in that set is 2 and 251 respectively.
I also supposed that since the the question denoted each of the three primes a, b, c with different letters that they are distinct and no one of them must be the same (I might be wrong here and maybe I made an incorrect assumption but it saves me one more tedious search by hand prime factorization.))

From the equations above that are bounded by the same values we can see that they have the same derivative and the first one has a bigger initial value so it is more likely that that one will need less checks.

So I start:

For $\ n=0$ for the first equation we have $\ n_1=7905$ which clearly is divisible by 5 and the second factor will definitely be over 251 for obvious reasons (I do not continue to find all the prime factors of it to not lose time since the question is about 2 prime factors and not more).

For $\ n=1$ for the first equation we have $\ n_1=21242$ which clearly is divisible by 2 and the second factor will definitely be over 251 for obvious reasons again.

For $\ n=2$ for the first equation we have $\ n_1=34579$ which has no obvious divisibility by an single digit prime so I tried another method.
THERE IS ANOTHER THEOREM WHICH STATES THE FOLLOWING: IF A NUMBER IS NOT PRIME THEN IT HAS ONE PRIME FACTOR THAT IS LESS THAN IT'S SQUARE ROOT.
sqrt(34579)=185.95 so if I am not unlucky and it is not a prime it will have at least one prime factor that is less than 185 so I reverse search if it is divisible by 181 or by 179, or by 173, or by 167, or by 163 or by 157 or by 151 which is one of its factors indeed and I found the other one to be 229 which is also prime, So it is a possible solution.

For n=3 for the first equation we have n1=47916 which is obviously divisible by 4 which is 2*2 so it must have more than 2 prime factors so it's not a solution.

For n=4 for the first equation n1=61253 > 60491 So it cannot be a valid solution

So after all that the possible values that a and b can have are 151 and 229.

Now in order to find c I will check for which of the following t values n2 is divisible by 151 or 229.

This one is easier and that is why I will not write it very analytically, but

For t=0 n2=4186 which is not divisible by either 151 or 229.

For t=1 n2=17523 which is not divisible by either 151 or 229.

For t=2 n2=30860 which is not obviously divisible by 10 so by 2 and 5 and thus it has definitely more than 2 prime factors.

For t=3 n2=44197 which is divisible by 229 and the other factor is 193 which is also prime. Early Hooray, since I found one solution, but I will continue to rule out that there are no other solutions.

For t=4 n2=57534 which is not divisible by either 151 or 229.

For t=5 n2=70871 > 60491 So I stop.

And thus after all these tedious that could be done by a computer in half a second max, I found the values of a,b,c which are the following:

a=229

b=151

c=193

So to Close off,
THANKS FOR LETTING ME COOK!!!

2 EXTRA NOTES The User Gerry Myerson has commemented the same solution but more concisely in a comment above and the User PM 2RING responded in the comments with a program that solves this question in a program! Here it is https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9jt0OgjAMhe%5F7FL1kSRPcUFAzn8WMyc8umGbw%5FrEFohKj567n9DvtgBfURVFUkDRhMjxWp92BcK%2DPJTxSGJqRvbGZsnm4Jhe7JjOE2tqjUtAHabBWlwDtPWHUGCIuW1LZB8JBnQFZc24%2DcrPNRY7rOn%5FLIrPRqJcfWo6YXF5674tqZvhunqPb%2DMzUvxiRF858cyvr%5F7EizuK0fkroCGtCr%2DAJL4JOqA==&lang=sage

Comment: Note that my suggestion didn't involve any factorization. Instead, it relied on a gcd calculation, which is less work.

Comment: Yeah Mr. Jerry you are actually right I did not catch that at first could you write your solution if you have time in the comments so people can see yours too. If you do not do it by tommorow don't worry I will try and write as close to what I think your solution is, but it would be super awesome, if you wrote it because you seem more familiar with the subject and definetely better than me at solving modular arithmetic problems in a concise and clever way!!